# What is the idiomatic way to map a Collection<Foo> onto a MultiMap<A, B>?

Tags: java, collections, functional-programming, guava, multimap

What is the idiomatic way to map a `Collection<Foo>` onto a `MultiMap<A, B>`? Were

```
public class Foo {
    public A key;
    public B val;
}
```

(This is simplified, of course.)

The way I can think to do it is to to use `Collection::stream()` to invoke `MultiMap::put` on each element, but I feel there might be a much more elegant way to do this.

And can a `new MultiMap` be returned with those mappings, all in one line?

Comment: Which MultiMap class are you talking about? From which library?

Comment: Maybe this https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html

Comment: the short answer is, yes, you can always define your own collector. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collector.html

Comment: if you're using Guava or some other library then please tag it otherwise please provide more context.

Comment: Assuming `MultiMap` has similar API as `Map` you can do this: `MultiMap<A, B> mm = list.stream().collect( MultiMap::new, (m, f) -> m.put( f.getKey(), f.getVal() ), MultiMap::putAll );`

Comment: how about: `mm.put (foo.key, foo.value)`?

Comment: Yes, I'm using Guava; sorry, being new to Java, I thought it was a core Java thing. And yes, collectors were what I needed! @tsolakp - You answer almost worked for me, but I am getting a "MultiMap is abstract; can't be instantiated" at the `new`. I'll try to figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since version 21.0 onwards, the most idiomatic way to do this is to use one of the collectors already provided by Guava, in this case the one provided by the [`Multimaps.toMultimap`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimaps.html#toMultimap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Supplier-) utility method:

```
Multimap<A, B> result = foos.stream()
    .collect(Multimaps.toMultimap(Foo::getA, Foo::getB, ArrayListMultimap::create));
```

This creates an `ArrayListMultimap`, but of course you can create the concrete `Multimap` you want, either by using a factory method or one of Guava's specific builders.